# How to use lapply with a formula?

Tags: list, r, lapply

I have a problem with the lapply function and I did not find any matching question posted earlier.
I need to apply a permutation test to all list elements, however I am not able to setup the lapply correctly.

I am trying this

```
testperm <- lapply(test-list, FUN=perm.test, formula=(cover ~ group))
```

the function perm.test is from the package 'exactRankTests'
cover is the dependent (numerical) variable and group is a factor.

Any hints on how to apply such a function would be very much appreciated.
jens

Comment: 'lapply' returns a list--that's what you want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use a formula, you often also need to supply a value to a `data` argument so the function knows which data to use. You data sets will be the list elements, so you need to use an anonymous function to supply them to perm.test.

In this case try:

```
testperm <- lapply(test.list, FUN=function(x) perm.test(formula=(cover ~ group),data=x))
```

Comment: Hi James, that looks useful, however, I receive the error: 'Error in test - list : non-numeric Argument for binary Operator'  hence it generally says that 'test-list' does not work?

Comment: `test-list` contains the minus symbol, which is invalid in variable names unless you use backtick notation, best to rename it `test.list`. I'll modify the answer using this name.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson I don't think that will work, because without anonymous functions, lapply only passes to the first argument of a function.

Comment: Ah sorry, misunderstood what test-list. You are correct. I'm going to delete my useless comment.

Comment: James, many thanks. Yes, that 'minus' was confusing. Now it works! Great!

Answer (score 2):

It's your *third* argument that you need to take a look at.

*lapply* takes (at least) *two* arguments, a *list* (incl. data frame) and a *function*, FUN, that operates on it:

```
data(iris)
df0 = iris[1:5,1:3]

fnx = function(v){v^2}

lapply(df0, fnx)
```

lapply accepts an optional *third* argument which must correspond to additional arguments required by FUN and *not* furnished by lapply's first argument data structure:

```
lapply( df0[,1], quantile, probs=1:3/4)
```

Comment: Hey Doug, thank you, I am aware of this example. It is quite simple. How does this work with a more complex thing like perm.test?